# Why can I not split a .wv file?

Tags: audio, conversion

I'm a Fedora 20 user and am trying to split a `.wv` file into separate `.flac` files. I used this command:

```
cuebreakpoints file.cue | shnsplit -o flac file.wv
```

but get the following output:

```
56: syntax error
cuebreakpoints: error: unable to parse input file `file.cue'
shnsplit: error: no split points given -- nothing to do
```

I don't know why this happens, since I've done this splitting using this same command going from `flac` to `flac`, and from `ape` to `flac`. The `wavpack` package is installed, though, so I feel even more puzzled.

If someone can help me solve this issue I would appreciate it.

---

**Answer to slm:** I installed as `cuetools` from the fedora repo:

```
Name        : cuetools
Arch        : i686
Version     : 1.4.0
Release     : 0.11.svn305.fc20
Size        : 150 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : fedora
Summary     : Utilities to work with cue and TOC files
URL         : http://developer.berlios.de/projects/cuetools/
License     : GPLv2
Description : Cuetools is a set of utilities for working with cue files and TOC
            : files. It includes programs for conversion between the formats,
            : file renaming based on cue/TOC information, and track breakpoint
            : printing.
```

---

**Answer to Anthon and slm:** I was glazing at the `.cue` file and here it is (I modified the `PPERFORMER`,`TITLE`, `FILE` and `TRACK` for it to be clearer):

```
PERFORMER "artist"
TITLE "album"
FILE "file.wv" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "track 01"
    PERFORMER "artist"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "track 02"
    PERFORMER "artist"
    INDEX 01 04:38:10
  TRACK 03 AUDIO
    TITLE "track 03"
    PERFORMER "artist"
    INDEX 01 08:28:55
  TRACK 04 AUDIO
    TITLE "track 04"
    PERFORMER "artist"
    INDEX 00 15:33:14
    INDEX 01 15:35:22
  TRACK 05 AUDIO
    TITLE "track 05"
    PERFORMER "artist"
    INDEX 01 22:15:62
  TRACK 06 AUDIO
    TITLE "track 06"
    PERFORMER "artist"
    INDEX 00 26:36:30
    INDEX 01 26:39:60
  TRACK 07 AUDIO
    TITLE "track 07"
    PERFORMER "artist"
    INDEX 01 35:13:65
  TRACK 08 AUDIO
    TITLE "track 08"
    PERFORMER "artist"
    INDEX 01 37:56:07
```

The only different things I noticed in my `.cue` file is that some tracks have more than one `INDEX` and that the `FILE` had some characters like `&`, `@`, `(` and `)`, but I don't know if this is a problem. Also, one track had the character `&` in its `TITLE` and every track had a `ISRC`, but I realized this is just an identifier.

Hope you can get a better view of the problem now. Ask me if you need any additional info and I will provide it.

Comment: Where did you get your version of cuebreakpoints? I'd suspect that it was compiled with some options missing. It's not in my Fedora 19 repos, double checking now + on F20. If it has a verbose switch I'd try that first. From there I'd try `strace cuebreakpoints file.cue`.

Comment: Can you point me to a sample `file.cue`?

Comment: @slm I edited the question to add a cue sheet example.

Answer (score 2):

It is obfuscated because you run multiple commands, but the only real error is in `cuebreakpoints` not being able to process the cue file. That you get an error from `shnsplit` as well is because `cuebreakpints` cannot pipe anything sensible into it.

Look at the `file.cue` for any obvious syntax errors, it should look like:

```
 REM GENRE "Electronica"
 REM DATE "1998"
 PERFORMER "Faithless"
 TITLE "Live in Berlin"
 FILE "Faithless - Live in Berlin.mp3" MP3
   TRACK 01 AUDIO
     TITLE "Reverence"
     PERFORMER "Faithless"
     INDEX 01 00:00:00
   TRACK 02 AUDIO
     TITLE "She's My Baby"
     PERFORMER "Faithless"
     INDEX 01 06:42:00
```

(the above is part of the example from the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cue_sheet_%28computing%29))

The problem in partially correct files is often in the encoding of some TITLE and/or PERFORMER. If I encounter those, I would remove any non-ASCII characters and use Musicbrainz Picard on the split FLAC material to re-add correct tags.

Comment: I added the cue sheet in case you want to take a look.